# Session implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

Today I found out about session data. I'm building a simple database project that gets, edits and writes data to/from an MS-Sql database.

My original problem was my `GridView` forgetting about its original data whenever I clicked an external edit button. Because a good fistful of the program is written in the page class, clicking a button (any button) forces the page to reload.

I'm semi-following an old StackOverflow article where a user gave an example of using an entirely separate class file to implement session storage - [see here](http://pastebin.com/hRRFY3PH)

Now, I've been trying to store my singular row cell-by-cell, as strings, but I cannot get them to remain in a session.

So far, I've been using the following line to transfer a cell to a session string:

```
masterSession.Current.K_INVOICE = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
```

Which doesn't work. How on earth to I go about implementing this?

Comment: Something sounds fishy about storing rows in a session.  Are you sure you are handling Page.IsPostBack correctly?  Your gridview should maintain its state even after postback just check `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`

Comment: @JonH The purpose of this project is largely to learn about C#, and by definition, session data. For this reason, I need to use the `session` variable.

Comment: Please specify "doesn't work".

Comment: @HansKesting When I try to retrieve session data to formulate an SQL query, I get `null` instead of any meaningful data.

Comment: Immediately after you assign `K_INVOICE`, try and read the value. Is that what you expect? Could you show (edit your question) your version of the code of `masterSession.Current` and the `K_INVOICE` property? Is anything else setting that property?

Comment: @HansKesting I had to somewhat change my code to meet some requirements. The process is still the same, but the session data is now assigned from within the page itself. The issue remains, as soon as the `button_click` method begins, the gridview loses all data. Thus, `K_INVOICE` is null as the gridview cannot assign anything to it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972716/implementing-session-data for the updated question.