# Implementing session data

Tags: c#, session, webforms

I have a web form that instantiates a class from within its default web page. The class implements session data, as does the web page, but I'm struggling to get the session to remain constant.

Each time the page reloads, it re-instantiates the class, and thus the session, rendering the entire concept of my session moot.

How does one implement a session without instantiating it in the page itself, or any classes that are instantiated from the page? Or have I got the wrong idea?

For reference, here is the page and sub-class. Where you see "..." some unnecessary code has been omitted:

**Sub class:**

```
public class invoiceHandler
{

    public HttpContext sessionContext = HttpContext.Current;

    ...
}
```

**Page:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{

Program.invoiceHandler handler = new Program.invoiceHandler();

...

protected void updateactionsGridBind()
    {
        handler.sessionContext = HttpContext.Current;
            try
            {
                invGrid.Columns[7].Visible = false;
                invGrid = (GridView)handler.sessionContext.Session["editaction"];

            ...
            }
        ...
    }

...

protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        handler.sessionContext = HttpContext.Current;
        invGrid.EditIndex = -1;
        string kinvConv = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
        handler.sessionContext.Session["editaction"] = invGrid;
        tools.i = kinvConv;
        tools.ToInt();

        handler.sessionContext.Session["kinv"] = tools.j;
        handler.sessionContext.Session["<REDACTED>"] = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
        handler.sessionContext.Session["sup"] = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text;
        handler.sessionContext.Session["supn"] = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text;
        handler.sessionContext.Session["net"] = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[4].Text;
        handler.sessionContext.Session["vat"] = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[5].Text;
        handler.sessionContext.Session["date"] = invGrid.Rows[0].Cells[6].Text;

        OnUpdate(sender, e);
    }
    ...
}
```

It is at the point of `savebutton_click` that the session appears to lose its data.

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: @TusharGupta Some snippets have been added

Comment: That `handler` as you use it in this code is fairly useless. Remove `handler.sessionContext.` and everything continues to work exactly as before.

Answer (score 1):

In your `saveButton_Click`, you are using a variable `invGrid`. You probably think you have assigned this a value in `updateactionsGridBind`, but my guess is that that happened before you showed your page and clicked on your saveButton.

A postback (or rather any request) uses a *new* instance of your page class, so any variables have been reset (in this case to null). You need to get that value again from session.

Comment: I'm aware that the variables have returned to `null`, but I'm not sure how to update the session with the edited data. Since the edit mode if the GridView is being controlled with external buttons, how do I update the session without "clicking" so to speak?

Comment: What is `invGrid` exactly? Just some class-level variable that you assign a value, or the GridView control that's placed on your page? If it's a control you *must not* store it in Session: that control-instance belongs to a specific page-instance and every request (or postback) is handled by a *different* page-instance. So it's a different control then.

Comment: `invGrid` is indeed my control. Should I be taking the celldata only? Or is that why my `button_Click` method is failing, because the gridview is not properly populated?

Comment: @Wolfish - When you (first) add values to the grid, guard that with an `if(!IsPostback)`. The postback processing should repopulate your grid, but that fails if you overwrite it.

Comment: Can this method also be applied to protect the edited values? This is where I'm having problems - I can enter edit mode and thus change values, but by repopulating the data I would subsequently lose those changes. I need to find out how I can prevent that, else the entire exercise is moot.

Comment: @Wolfish - you don't need to repopulate yourself on postback, ViewState should take care of that. Then save the changed values.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code samples provided, I am not entirely certain that you understand how [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) works. You appear to be using it to cache the current state of the context. (I could be completely wrong!)

`HttpContext.Current` is a static value. Creating a property that represents it achieves little besides creating a shortcut to it. It most certainly would not cause you to lose state between page postbacks.

Similarly, [`HttpContext.Current.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static value. As such, it will not lose values between page postbacks, unless:

1. Something causes session state to be discarded, such as IIS or the application pool being restarted
2. Session state is disabled for the page, request, or application
3. You are no longer on the same session.

Check to verify that you have not disabled session state for the request, the page, or the application. Also, check to verify that you have cookies enabled. (Session state is typically enabled through the use of a cookie.)